# Excel VBA IF OR

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Please help to run this formula if the cell C2 value is saturday

```
Range("F2").Formula = "=IF(AND(D2>=TIME(9,16,0),D2<=TIME(11,59,0)),D2-TIME(9,0,0),IF(AND(D2>=TIME(14,16,0),D2>=TIME(12,00,0)),D2-TIME(14,0,0)*1,0))"
```

and if Cell C2 value is Sunday to Friday

```
Range("F2").Formula = "=IF(AND(D2>=TIME(8,16,0),D2<=TIME(10,30,0)),D2-TIME(8,0,0),IF(AND(D2>=TIME(12,16,0),D2>=TIME(10,31,0)),D2-TIME(12,0,0)*1,0))"
```

Until the last row which has data in the sheet.

In short check the value in C2, if = saturday formula 1 or formula 2.

From C2 onwards Column C contains date. eg

```
05/03/2019
```

[Sample Excel file Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QryNt.jpg) 
[image]

Comment: use the weekday() function

Comment: I tried and failed many times , Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        If Weekday(Range("C" & i)) = 7 Then
            Range("F" & i).Formula = "=IF(AND(D" & i & ">=TIME(9,16,0),D" & i & "<=TIME(11,59,0)),D" & i & "-TIME(9,0,0),IF(AND(D" & i & ">=TIME(14,16,0),D" & i & ">=TIME(12,00,0)),D" & i & "-TIME(14,0,0)*1,0))"
        Else
            Range("F" & i).Formula = "=IF(AND(D" & i & ">=TIME(8,16,0),D" & i & "<=TIME(10,30,0)),D" & i & "-TIME(8,0,0),IF(AND(D" & i & ">=TIME(12,16,0),D" & i & ">=TIME(10,31,0)),D" & i & "-TIME(12,0,0)*1,0))"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear dwirony, 

Thanks for the reply, It works in the first row, i need code to run this formula  in entire work sheet. ( until the last row with data )

Thank you.

Comment: The reference cell for row 2 is C2 and for row 3 is C3 and goes on, 
formula woks only in row 2 with the code you gave

Comment: @Jagadeesh See my new post

Comment: Thank you dwirony. It works. You solved my problem.

Comment: Could u please give me same solution for these two formulas also ?

Range("G2").Formula = "=IF(AND(E2<=TIME(15,59,0),D2<=TIME(10,29,0)),TIME(16,0,0)-E2,IF(AND(E2<=TIME(19,59,0),D2>=TIME(10,31,0)),TIME(20,0,0)-E2*1,1))"


Range("G2").Formula = "=IF(AND(E2<=TIME(13,59,0),D2<=TIME(11,59,0)),TIME(14,0,0)-E2,IF(AND(E2<=TIME(19,59,0),D2>=TIME(12,00,0)),TIME(20,0,0)-E2*1,1))"

Comment: @Jagadeesh If your question has changed, please open a new question and I/we can help you there :). But if you look are the example above, you should be able to adopt the logic in yourself no problem.

Comment: Thank you very much dwirony for your help. youi solved my problem 100% Thanks again